# Run QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS once for multiple files

Tags: qmake

Is it possible to have a QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS target that is only run once for multiple inputs? I have a few legacy scripts that generate all the files at once.

Say something like this:

```
FILE_LIST = __Test1.cpp __Test2.cpp __Test.h

Extra.name = Extra Compilers Tests
Extra.input = FILE_LIST
Extra.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
Extra.commands += <generate what is in FILE_LIST with a single command>
Extra.CONFIG   += no_link target_predeps ordered
Extra.variable_out = GENERATED_SOURCES

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += Extra
```

I could possibly rewrite the scripts but it would be nice if I could get QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS to do the work for me.

Oce

Comment: I've sort of found what I was looking for with the CONFIG options "combine".

Answer (score 1):

I've sort of found what I'm looking for with the "combine" option.

So say we have something like this.

```
ExtraGen.name =  Id Generator
ExtraGen.input = GENINPUT
ExtraGen.output = $$GENOUTPUT
ExtraGen.clean_command = $$ExtraGen.output
ExtraGen.commands = <Process> ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
ExtraGen.CONFIG = combine
ExtraGen.variable_out = HEADERS
#silent:ExtraGen.commands = @echo Processing ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} && $$ExtraGen.commands
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += ExtraGen
```

So this works great as long as GENOUTPUT is defined before ExtraGen. Which is sort of a pain since I'd like to define ExtraGen in an included pri file.

Is there any way around this or have I backed myself into a corner?

Oce

Comment: This should have been a question on it's own. Nevertheless, maybe try `${QMAKE_VAR_GENOUTPUT}`. That is an undocumented feature which makes qmake expand the variabel `GENOUTPUT` at "runtime". However, I'm not sure whether that works for `.output`.